# Numbers of intersection points and lines

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry

Hello,

I don't know if this question has already been posted, I have made a little search with keywords and did not found it, sorry if I missed anything.

Is it possible to characterize the set of pairs of integers ($l$,$i$) such that one can draw $l$ lines on the euclidean plane with exactly $i$ intersection points?

It is quite trivial to see is that given $l$, an upper bound for $i$ is $l(l+1)/2$.
More generally, given $l$, any additive decomposition of $l$ of the form $\underset{j=1}{\overset{k}{\sum}} l_i$ provides a value for $i$ which is $\underset{i=1}{\overset{k}{\sum}} $ $\underset{j>i}{\overset{k}{\sum}} l_i l_j$ if we fix for any $i \in [1,k]$ exactly $l_i$ parallel lines such that there is no intersection of three or more lines at the same point.

It is not difficult to see that there are pairs ($l$,$i$) that are not of this form.
For instance, if you try all decompositions of 6, you may draw 6 lines with 5, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14 or 15 intersection points with this method, but 7 and 10 are missing (they can be obtained with intersection points of three lines).

Here is a link containing some observations (http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/junkyard/how-many-intersects.html). As far as I know, this is the only place where this problem has been seriously considered, but it is quite old and maybe lacks of results. So any additional comment will be welcomed :)

Just a final remark, thanks to some projective properties, this question is the same as finding $c$ circles sharing a common point with exactly $i+1$ intersection points. Don't know if this can help.

Comment: The expert on this topic is Branko Grünbaum, who recently summarized his extensive knowledge in the book, _Configurations of Points and Lines_: http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=GSM-103 .


Comment: So if you count points of infinity, each pair of lines must intersect one. The intersection of $k$ lines has multiplicity $k(k-1)/2$. Also your upper bound for $l$ lines should probably be $l(l-1)/2$. So you take $l(l-1)/2$, partition it into smaller triangular numbers, throw out the ones at infinity, and count the remaining ones.

Comment: @Will: Easier said than done.

Comment: A related question is to characterize the pairs $(\ell,r)$ such that one can draw $\ell$ lines in the plane dividing the plane into exactly $r$ regions. This was discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38350/n-lines-cannot-divide-a-plane-region-into-x-regions-finding-x-for-n and, given Euler's formula, perhaps some of the discussion and references there would be relevant. 

Comment: Thanks Joseph for the book however it won't be possible for me to read it :/

You're right Will, that's l(l-1)/2, not l(l+1)/2

Thanks Gerry for this discussion, I will take a look at this, maybe this can help

Comment: I need to correct myself above.  Although Grünbaum is surely the expert, the book I cited uses a very particular meaning of "configuration": An $n_k$ *configuration* is a set of $n$ points and a set of $n$ lines so that every point lies on precisely $k$ of the lines and every line contains precisely $k$ of the points.  There can be many line intersections that are superfluous for these configurations.  For example, the Pappus configuration is a $9_3$ configuration although there are more than 9 line-line intersections.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I asked Jon Lenchner, an expert on point-line incidences, and he told me the
question (in dual form) was posed in 
Grünbaum's 1971 book
*[Arrangements and Spreads](http://books.google.com/books/about/Arrangements_and_spreads.html?id=2L5Mgc-6vN8C)*,
and fully answered in a paper by 
Peter Salamon and
Paul Erdős:
"The solution to a problem of Grünbaum,"
*Canad. Math. Bull.* **31**: 129-138 (1988).
Here are its first two sentences:

> In the paper below we characterize for large $n$ the possible values of the
>   number of connecting lines determined by a set of $P_n$ points in the plane,
>   where a connecting line is any straight line containing at least two points of $P_n$.
>   This solves a problem posed by Grünbaum [5,6] which asks for the sequence
>   of all integers $m$ with the property that some configuration of $n$ 
>   points determine exactly $m$ lines.

([6] is *Arrangements and Spreads*; [5] is Erdős's earlier partial solution.)
They obtain exact expressions "for the lower end of the continuum of values leading
down from $\binom{n}{2}-4$."  "The possible values...can be seen to bear a strong resemblance
to physical spectra."
The lower end of the continuum grows as $n^{3/2}$ (with constant 1).
Here are two figures from the paper:

     [image: SE Fig1]
     [image: SE Fig4]

Comment: Joseph, can you elaborate on the nature of the duality here?  It seems to me there might be something at stake in the difference.  In particular, it's easy to get $n$ lines to have zero points of intersection, but a lot harder to get $n$ points to determine less than one line.

Comment: @Barry: I think the distinction only occurs in the Euclidean plane, but in the projective plane, $n$ "parallel" lines meet at one point at infinity, and $n$ collinear points determine just one line. 

Comment: That's very nice, thanks a lot for this reference! 