# intersection points and lines, part two

Tags: combinatorial-geometry

Two years ago I asked a question about finding couples of integers (p,l) such that one may draw l lines on the euclidean plane, creating exactly p intersection points, and I got very interesting comments and references.

([Numbers of intersection points and lines](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/82622/numbers-of-intersection-points-and-lines))

I'd like now to discuss the problem on the torus ; so far, it seems to me that the problem has not been investigated in this framework.

Here are a few really trivial comments as an introduction. With 0 and 1 line, there is 0 point of intersection. With 2 lines, one may have any integer as the number of intersection points (take an horizontal line and a correctly chosen slanted line). With 3 lines, it is possible to draw lines such that there are exactly 1, 3, or any even number of intersection points. The most generalized result I have found is that, given n lines, for any k between 0 and n, one may draw k parallel lines and (n-k) other parallel lines, creating this way exactly k(n-k)j intersection points, where j may be any integer (consider for starting figure k horizontal lines and (n-k) vertical lines for the k(n-k) result, then replace vertical lines by slanted lines correctly chosen).

Is it possible to say more? It's up to you now, thanks by advance for any comment :)

Comment: I think a link to your earlier question would be in order. Also, I take it that for you a torus is a square in the plane, aligned with the axes, with opposite edges identified.

Comment: You're totally right Gerry, thanks for the suggestion. Concerning the torus, I did not mention what seems quite obvious since I don't think there is another way of viewing the torus (but maybe this was too tacit)

Comment: Your presentation is basically unique for the flat torus, up to linear transformations, but one can also consider geodesics on bumpy tori.

Comment: Well, of course others surfaces may be considered, but I think the problem on the "natural" torus is already challenging enough.